# Propagating changes from a local repository to another local repository

Tags: git, permissions, workflow

On the same machine, user A owns a repository and user B owns a clone of the repository. How do I propagate user A's changes to user B's repository (taking into consideration user permissions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have user A use "git commit" to commit the changes, then have user B do a "git pull".  Since the B repo is a clone of A, you can use the auto-generated remote alias "origin" that aliases repo A's location:  "git pull origin (branch name)".

Comment: I know this post is quite old, but... In repo B, will any alterations need to be made after the pull from repo A? Basically, will the origin have to be reset? // I doubt this is so, because `git pull origin master` should refer to the remote master...?