# How to rebase a local repository from another local repository

Tags: git

I have two directories on same machine. One of them has committed changes that I want to propagate to the other *in the same branch*.

Here is latest commit seen from `git log` on the "source" directory:

```
commit ef643298f6c354705eba866d42d53aff0d74d911
Author: javadba <javadba@email.org>
Date:   Wed Jun 8 15:02:25 2016 -0700

    Added binary level backward compatibility to Spark 1.X.
```

Doing a `pull` from the second directory - as recommended here  [Propagating changes from a local repository to another local repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439619/propagating-changes-from-a-local-repository-to-another-local-repository) - does not do anything:

```
$git pull origin spark20
From https://github.com/myuser/myrepo
 * branch            spark20    -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

We can see it has older commit as last entry in `git log`:

```
commit fbf05bbcdb69beb200bdedf182363b145ee4a3d1
Author: javadba <javadba@email.org>
Date:   Wed Jun 8 13:19:41 2016 -0700

    Added source level backward compatibility to Spark 1.X
```

So then how to allow the second directory to see the locally committed changes in the first one?

Comment: You will be able to pull changes in the second directory if you set the other one as the origin.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk  Thanks. please create answer and following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603671/git-how-to-add-a-local-repo-and-treat-it-as-a-remote-one

Comment: As per SO rules I should vote for duplicate, I hope you have nothing against that, really glad that my comment helped you.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk  Sure fair enough.  thx for the help.

Comment: It isn't an exact duplicate, because you don't need to set it as a remote, you just need to pull it by path instead of name. `git pull <full path to other repo> <branch>:<branch>`

Comment: @BryceDrew That is a different approach .  feel free to answer.

Comment: I Tried. Answers are locked.